# How to query for an array item that belongs to a user?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Hey so how do I query a specific array item that belongs to a user's friend collection.

Here is the query:

```
Friend.find({userId: req.signedCookies.userid, 'friendStatus.labels': req.body.searchLabels
            }, function(err, users) {
```

This broken down is the userId is a way to find the signed In User's document then I want to just access the labels inside the labels array that is nested in an object that is inside the friendStatus array...

here is an example of a document:

```
> db.friends.find({'firstName': "test3"}).pretty()
{
        "__v" : 0,
        "_id" : ObjectId("520a4944c24d995410000008"),
        "accepted_notifications" : true,
        "added_notifications" : true,
        "firstName" : "test3",
        "firstNameTrue" : "test3",
        "friendStatus" : [
                {
                        "favorites" : 1,
                        "fuId" : ObjectId("520a4905c24d995410000001"),
                        "labels" : [
                                "new",
                                "old"
                        ],
                        "notes" : "He likes me",
                        "status" : 3
                },
                {
                        "fuId" : ObjectId("520a4925c24d995410000004"),
                        "labels" : [ ],
                        "notes" : "sadwa",
                        "status" : 3
                }
        ],
        "lastName" : "test3s",
        "lastNameTrue" : "TEST3s",
        "notifications" : 0,
        "userId" : ObjectId("520a4944c24d995410000007")
}
```

and the current query returns the whole document when I use the callback users, but I just want to pull this out of it for the matching labels:

```
{
                            "favorites" : 1,
                            "fuId" : ObjectId("520a4905c24d995410000001"),
                            "labels" : [
                                    "new",
                                    "old"
                            ],
                            "notes" : "He likes me",
                            "status" : 3
                    },
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the aggregation framework to achieve this, specifically the `$match` and `$project` operators. `$match` matches documents much like a regular query, and `$project` allows you to select which fields to return in the query output. An aggregate query for your setup might look like this:

```
Friend.aggregate([{$match: {userId: req.signedCookies.userid,'friendStatus.labels': req.body.searchLabels}}, {$project: {'friendStatus.labels': 1}}])
```

More documentation can be found here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/operators/